# How to detect when Scrollbar size changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is a listener to find when scrollbar value changed:

```
Scrollbar.onValueChanged.AddListener(scollBarChanged);
```

...

```
private void scollBarChanged(float value)
{
    //Do something
}
```

I want a listener for scrollbar size changed and not value in c# for unity

Comment: There is nothing built-in. Try to trigger the event from where you add/remove items.

Comment: Something need to trigger the resizing, maybe could you get an adequate event from a parent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is event is **not** available in the `Scrollbar` component but you can implement it by checking in the `Update` function when the `Scrollbar.size` property changes. Just compare it with the old  `Scrollbar.size` value with the `Mathf.Approximately` function. It's better to do it this way since Unity's UI mechanism will also be modifying it so checking it every frame is required.

Here is an example of how to detect the `Scrollbar.size` changes:

```
public Scrollbar scrollBar;
private float oldValue;

void Start()
{
    oldValue = scrollBar.size;
}

void Update()
{
    //Check if size changed
    if (!Mathf.Approximately(oldValue, scrollBar.size))
    {
        //It changed. Update old value with the new value
        oldValue = scrollBar.size;

        //Show the data
        Debug.Log("Size Changed!: " + scrollBar.size);
    }
}
```

---

You can also add event to it so that you can subscribe to it from other script:

```
public Scrollbar scrollBar;
private float oldValue;

public delegate void SizeChanged(float oldValue, float newValue);
public event SizeChanged OnSizeChanged;

void Start()
{
    oldValue = scrollBar.size;
}

void Update()
{
    //Check if size changed
    if (!Mathf.Approximately(oldValue, scrollBar.size))
    {
        //Invoke the event
        if (OnSizeChanged != null)
            OnSizeChanged(oldValue, scrollBar.size);

        //It changed. Update old value with the new value
        oldValue = scrollBar.size;
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to it from another script:

```
ScrollSizeChanger otherScript;

void Awake()
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("OtherObj");
    otherScript = obj.GetComponent<ScrollSizeChanger>();
}

void OnEnable()
{
    //Reigister to event
    otherScript.OnSizeChanged += SizeChangedCallBack;
}

private void SizeChangedCallBack(float oldValue, float newValue)
{
    Debug.Log("Size changed. Old value: " + oldValue + " New value: " + newValue);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Reigister to event
    otherScript.OnSizeChanged -= SizeChangedCallBack;
}
```

**Note**:

If the size you want to check is transform scale of this UI Object instead of `Scrollbar.size` then the-same thing still apply. Simply change `float oldValue;` to `Vector2 oldValue;` and then use `scrollBar.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta` to get the size instead of `scrollBar.size`. In the `Update` function, also compare the `Vector2` directly without `Mathf.Approximately`.